# How to get PDF output to look exactly like HTML output

Tags: html, django, pdf

I am trying to create a PDF for my client to start invoicing their clients. I've dealt with creating PDFs in the past and remember it was a huge pain to create them. In my Django application, I have two view functions, one that just renders a template that I am using to design the invoice, and another that converts it into a pdf and renders the PDF as well. I have two tabs open side by side one that points to each version template HTML vs. PDF and they look completely different. Is there a special Markup language I have to use to create PDFs, or is their a python package out their that converts HTML to an exact replica of that HTML in PDF ?

View Functions

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from io import BytesIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa


def generate_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render({})
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None

def ronin(request):
    template = get_template('ronin.html')
    context = {}
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = generate_pdf('ronin.html', context)
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" % ("12341231")
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" % (filename)
        download = request.GET.get("download")
        if download:
            content = "attachment; filename='%s'" % (filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Not found")

def ronin_html(request):
    template = 'ronin.html'
    context = {}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body style="margin: 0;">

<style>
    #invoice-template {
        padding: 100px 100px 50px 100px
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table#main {
        border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray; width: 100%;
    }

    td.header.first {
        border-bottom: 1px solid darkgray;
        border-right: 1px solid darkgray;
        padding: 1% 4%;
        width: 20%;
    }

    td.header.second {
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    td.header.second .contact-details td {
        padding: 15px;
    }

    td.header.second .address td {
        padding: 15px;
    }

    td.header.second p {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="invoice-template">

    <table id="main" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="header first">
                <img src="/static/images/logo_dark.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td class="header second">
                <table>
                    <tr class="address">
                        <td>
                            <p>ADDRESS</p>
                            <p>ADDRESS EXAMPLE St. CITY, STATE 11111</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="contact-details">
                        <td>
                            <p>PHONE</p>
                            <p>+1 111 222 3333</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>WEBSITE</p>
                            <p>Website.com</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>FOCUS</p>
                            <p>WEBSITES / MOBILE APPS</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

HTML VIEW
[image]

PDF VIEW
[image]

Comment: If you need your PDF to look *exactly* like the HTML does: they have different objectives so that's not possible. A screenshot of the HTML would be closest.

Comment: Maybe you could print to pdf from a browser, though printing tends to change the look too. Could always embed a screenshot in PDF – silly, but I've seen it done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Create automated strictly-designed multi-page .pdf report from .html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091524/python-create-automated-strictly-designed-multi-page-pdf-report-from-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to run into rendering issues with most HTML to PDF libraries, particularly if they are using WebKit as their engine.  I'd recommend using a combination of Puppeteer (to create a headless chrome instance of the page and take a screenshot, which will be a true 1:1 replica of the page) and PDFKit to take those images and attach them to a pdf document.

Of course, this relies on you knowing that the invoices will be no bigger than a full PDF page, or if they are, you'll need to know how to separate the content into separate pages.

Those are puzzles that need to be solved if you really want a 1:1 replica in PDF form.

Otherwise, I'd recommend using something like wkhtmltopdf to get a reasonably good approximation.